# File Processing with Workflow Foundation

Tags: workflow-foundation, file-processing

I have been tasked with building a new workflow system to handle our service orders.  I have been investigating Windows Workflow Foundation as the engine for managing the workflow steps, and like what I see up until file processing.

We have a step in our workflow where we are waiting for a file to be returned from a vendor. The file contains multiple records each mapping to an individual workflow.  The idea was to use the persistence features within WF so that once the data is returned in the file, the rest of the workflow can continue.

The problem with the persistence model is the scalability of calling the WF service for each line in a file using something like SSIS. For small files this isn't an issue, but there is the possibility for the files to get very large.

Has anyone done anything similar to this with Workflow Foundation?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: I don't understand about calling the WF service once per line. Please elaborate.

Comment: The current thought is to have a WCF Service that hosts the WF logic. Anything that needs access to the workflow would call into the WCF service.

Comment: Just so I understand your problem, the file you are watching for might have multiple workflows inside of it? And when a new record, with the workflow XOML in it, arrives in the file, your workflow creates an instance of it and lets it run?

Comment: The file we are waiting for is just an XML file from one of our vendors using their own schema.  The workflow would have been working for several steps by this point and has been dehydrated while waiting for a response. Since the workflow has been out of memory for some period of time (24 hours usually), we need to rehydrate the workflow so the rest of the flow can continue. If we just update the database directly using the data within the file, the workflows would never be re-hydrated and the flows won't continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be to create a custom WCF channel based upon reading/writing files from a directory. Then your workflow can use the normal WCF Send/Receive activities and you can easily mock up a test service (with a more standard channel). There's a good blog post series at http://blogs.msdn.com/drnick/archive/2006/04/17/577354.aspx about this, though it's a little outdated. I found I had to implement some additional methods from the abstract class. I also made changes to support one-way channels (the series covers Request/Reply).